# Symfony 3 - authentication

Tags: authentication, authorization, symfony

I'm trying to do authentication in Symfony 3. For example [How to Load Security Users from the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.)

Entity User and schema database I did like the documentation.
I tried use password with md5, bcrypt, plaintext

Security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER]

    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity: { class: AppBundle:User, property: username }

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern:    ^/
            anonymous: ~
            provider: our_db_provider

            form_login:
                login_path: /
                check_path: /
            logout:
                 path:   /logout
                 target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

In login form I have _username and _password

Controller:

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();

    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    if ($this->get('security.authorization_checker')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')){
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_dashboard'));
    }

    return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        'body_id' => "simple-page",
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error'         => $error
    ]);
}
```

How do I give incorrect data to login to get

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException' with message 'Bad credentials.'
```

As I will correct it does not redirect me to admin_dashboard and does not return any error. The debugging I'm still as anonymous

In database I have a role ROLE_ADMIN and such we have in getRoles returned to the User entity.

What is wrong?

Comment: It's hard to understand you.What is wrong, you don't have the exception?

Answer (score 0):

check the Symfony documentation. Remember your User Entity must implement UserInterface class. [here you can find what you need](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html)

also you can implement your own authentication system

```
class WeirdFormAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
```